# How to update the input filed value from an api in reactjs using react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

I want to implement update form in ReactJS. I have created a form using rect-hook-form library. I will fetch the userdata from an api and these values should be autofilled with the input fields of my form. When the user changes  any filed it should be update in the database.
I tried with the following code but with no luck. Can anyone please help me.

```
enter code here
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

function Updatenew() {
const { register, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm();

useEffect(() => {
// Fetch data from server and update form fields
 axios.get("http://localhost:8080/data").then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data);
  const { field1, field2 } = response.data;
  setValue("field1", field1);
  setValue("field2", field2);
 });
 }, []);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
  console.log(data);
 };

 return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <label htmlFor="field1">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="field1" {...register("field1")} />

  <br />
  <br />

  <label htmlFor="field2">Mobile No</label>
  <input type="text" id="field2" {...register("field2")} />

  <br />
  <br />

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  );
 }

 export default Updatenew;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code may be help you. I included in useForm {values:data} to retreive field filled and the defaultValue={data.field1} in each input to show field filled as well.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

function Updatenew() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const { register, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm({values:data});
    useEffect(() => {
// Fetch data from server and update form fields
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/data").then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    setData(response.data)

});
}, []);

const onSubmit = (data) => {
console.log(data);
};

return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <label htmlFor={data.field1}>Name</label>
  <input type="text" id={data.field1} {...register(data.field1)} defaultValue={data.field1}/>

  <br />
  <br />

  <label htmlFor={data.field1}>Mobile No</label>
  <input type="text" id={data.field2} {...register(data.field2)} defaultValue={data.field2}/>

  <br />
  <br />

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  );
}``

export default Updatenew;
```